# When $\int_{-\pi}^\pi |x|^\alpha |\tan x |^\beta dx < \infty$ and $\int_{-\pi}^\pi |\tan x |^\gamma dx < \infty$? Closed forms?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

For which $\alpha>0, \beta \in (0,2), \gamma \in (0,2)$ do we have  $$\int_{-\pi}^\pi |x|^\alpha |\tan x |^\beta dx < \infty$$  $$\int_{-\pi}^\pi |\tan x |^\gamma dx < \infty?$$

Can you also give a closed-form expression for the antiderivatives (or the definite integrals)?

Comment: the second one should be $$2\pi\sec\left(\frac{\gamma\pi}{2}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs at $x = \pm \pi/2$.  As $x \to \pi/2$ we have $\tan(x) \sim -(x - \pi/2)^{-1}$, so your integrals will be finite if $\beta < 1$ and $\gamma < 1$.

I would not expect there to be closed-form antiderivatives in the first integral.  For the second, I get

$$ \int \tan(x)^\gamma \; dx = \frac{\tan(x)^{\gamma+1}}{2} \Phi\left( -{\tan(x)}^{2},1,\frac{\gamma+1}2
 \right)$$
where $\Phi$ is the [Lerch Phi function](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=LerchPhi), defined by
$$ \Phi(z,a,v) = \sum _{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^k}{(v+k)^a}$$

For rational $\gamma$ you'll get more elementary forms of this antiderivative.

Comment: How do you prove that $\tan(x) \sim -(x - \pi/2)^{-1}$ as $x \to \frac{\pi}{2}$?

Comment: You can use l'Hôpital, for example.

Comment: If $\beta\in (1,2)$, can we obtain the convergence of the integral by taking a certain $\alpha$?

Comment: No, because that won't change anything as $x \to \pi/2$.